# Maintain state into a asyncNotifier

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, riverpod

I have to manage Two authentification into a Flutter app.
The main one is maintain with firebase authentication.
For the other one I've create a `AsyncNotifier` with my `OtherUser` object.

The idea here is to maintain trough all app this current `OtherUser`.

Here is what I've imagined :

```
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

class PatientController extends AsyncNotifier<Patient?> {
  PatientController();

  bool firstBuild = true;
  static PatientController patientController = PatientController();

  @override
  Future<Patient?> build() async {
    return null;
  }

  void logInPatient({
    required String firstName,
    required String lastName,
    required DateTime birthday,
  }) async {
    
    state = const AsyncLoading();
    state = await AsyncValue.guard(() async {
      final patient = await ref.read(repositoryProvider).getPatient(
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName: lastName,
            birthday: birthday,
          );
      return patient;
    });
  }

  void createPatient(
      {required String firstName,
      required String lastName,
      required DateTime birthday,
      }) async {
    state = const AsyncLoading();
    state = await AsyncValue.guard(() async {
      final patient = await ref.read(repositoryProvider).createPatient(
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName: lastName,
            birthday: birthday,
          );
      ref.read(routerProvider).go('/doctor/patient/home');
      return patient;
    });
  }

  void updatePatient(
      {required String firstName,
      required String lastName,
      required DateTime birthday,}) {
    update((data) async {
      state = const AsyncLoading();
      final patient = data!.copyWith(
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
        birthday: birthday,
      );

      await ref.read(repositoryProvider).updatePatient(patient: patient);
      return patient;
    });
  }

  void logPatientOut() {
    update((data) {
      // do stuff
      return null;
    });
  }

}

final patientControllerProvider =
    AsyncNotifierProvider<PatientController, Patient?>(
        () => PatientController.patientController);
```

Finally it's a kind of a singleton.

It's working but I'm clearly not sure it's best practice.
Otherwise It would always call rebuild And I should pass an String as an id to fetch id all through the app.

Do you have any idea how I should achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do it like this:

```dart
final patientControllerProvider =
    AsyncNotifierProvider<PatientController, Patient?>(PatientController.new);
```

Your `build()` method is empty and has no dependencies. It will not rebuild unless you decide to explicitly call `invalidate/refresh` or call `dispose()` on the whole container. Also, you do not apply the `autoDispose` modifier, so the `patientControllerProvider` will not be disposed.

Comment: It never gets dispose while the app is up and running ? It was I thought But I did tried and it doesn't work out as I wanted.
I will try again

Comment: add `ref.onDispose((){print('been Dispose');});` to the provider for easy debugging